# Display js array acquired via JSON to webpage

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json

Sorry if causing troubles again =x

With the help from you guys especially Scott Harwell,  I managed to get my php array passed to js array with the following code:

```
var horse_array = <?php echo json_encode($horse_info);?>;
```

However, now I encounter problem in displaying the content of array. I could not load it into my html tag with id="horse1_r".

The following is my js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var horse_array = <?php echo json_encode($horse_info);?>;

function goto1(hid) {

$("#horse1_r").html(horse_array); 

}

</script>
```

Your kind help will be much appreciated.

Comment: alert(horse_array) and see what you get

Comment: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

This is what I got. It means? Sorry, It is my first encounter with jquery json. So hope for your tolerance =)

Comment: maybe you should review the horse_array and see how you are getting your content. what does the content of this variable look like in php?(please add it to your question not in the comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the contents of the Javascript object, you can return it to a string:

```
$('#horse1_r').html(JSON.stringify(horse_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that I don't see the function goto1 being called. With jQuery you will have to run it in document.ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var horse_array = <?php echo json_encode($horse_info);?>;

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#horse1_r").html(horse_array); 

});
</script>
```

Now the second thing is that horse_array will be an array containing maybe other arrays (or objects in JavaScript for that matter). You will have to loop through these arrays and objects and output it's properties the way you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

First, `json_encode` returns a string, you have to decode it to JSON in JavaScrpt.

Second, you have to call `goto1`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goto1(horse_array) {
        // $("#horse1_r").html(); 
        // use horse_array
    }
    var horse_array = $.parseJSON(<?php echo json_encode($horse_info);?>);
    goto1(horse_array);
</script>
```

PS: I think you should modify the goto1 function, it doen't make sense to me.